# Toggle UIBarButtonItem on KeyboardDidShow

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uibarbuttonitem, keyboard-events

**Purpose**: I am attempting to toggle the "Save" UIBarButtonItem with the "Hide Keyboard" UIBarButtonItem whenever the Keyboard appears (and then do the opposite when the "Hide Keyboard" button is clicked).

So far I have created two UIBarButtonItems and connected them both to Interface Builder.

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *saveButton;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *hideKeyButton;
```

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code I have setup so far in my main:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Show HideKey Button
    // Hide Save Button
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Show Save Button
    // Hide HideKey Button
}
```

On Interface Builder, the Save button is present by default. Programatically, how do I show the HideKey button and Hide the Save button? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to make this work.

First, you need to register for the notifications, what you can do is, in your viewDidLoad, add the following:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardDidShow:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification
                                           object:nil];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Secondly, in your event handlers, simply set the buttons:

```
- (void)keyboardDidShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = hideKeyButton;
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = saveButton;
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thank you. What's the reasoning behind Xcode adding the underscore before the object. Example: `_saveButton` opposed to `saveButton`.

Comment: they actually points to the same thing. One of three things you can do: 1) use `_saveButton`, 2) use `self.saveButton`; 3) add `@synthesize saveButton` to beginning of yr .m, after @implementation, now you do not need self. any more, and you can simply say `saveButton`. all three are the same indeed.

Comment: I had no idea! I was getting so confused between the @synthesize and the 'self'. Thank you for clearing this up for me. Still a programmer in training. :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using IB for this task, I would do it programmatically.

Something like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem *saveButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave
                                                                             target:self
                                                                             action:@selector(saveButtonPressed:)];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:saveButton];
```

And in a similar fashion to create and set the HideKey button.

Then, of course you may want to cache the `UIBarButtonItem`s, setting lazy `@properties` for them.